# couln't find file 'chosen-jquery' error during deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, jquery-chosen

I am trying to deploy an app in rails 3.2.16, with capistrano on a vps. This is my first time doing that. During the deployment process, I get the following error: "couldn't find file "chosen-jquery" '. The rpoblem is that my gem versions and generally the whole environment is the same on the server and my testing machine. I get the error during the "assets:precompile" command execution.

Any suggestions?

I am using the gem chosen -v 1.0.2, rails 3.2.16 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.16'

gem 'mysql2'

group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'ckeditor', '4.0.4'
gem 'carrierwave', '0.8.0'
gem 'devise', '2.2.3'
gem 'globalize3', '0.3.0'
gem 'babosa', '0.3.9'
gem 'haml', '4.0.4'
gem 'friendly_id', '4.0.9'
gem 'simple_form', '2.0.4'
gem 'kaminari', '0.14.0'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.1'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails', '0.4.0'
gem 'ancestry', '1.3.0'
gem 'ransack', '0.7.2'
gem 'simple-navigation', '3.10.0'
gem 'mime-types', '~>1.21'
gem 'mini_magick', '3.5.0'
gem 'acts_as_list', '0.1.9'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'pry'

gem 'passenger'
```

and my application.js manifest:

```
//= require jquery-1.10.2.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack
//= require jquery.easing-1.3.pack
//= require jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require scripts
//= require admin_scripts
```

Thank you in advance for your time and effort :)

Comment: You can try require the library manually (as file). Will there the same error ?

Comment: No the error disappears. Hopefully there won't be any "overridings" in the js. As I can see it works fine. Thanks :)

Comment: Could I issue this as an answer? )

Answer (score 1):

You can try require the library manually (as file)

Answer (score 1):

Just restart rails server. I had the same problem on Rails 4.1.5. I restarted rails server and it worked. See this [Github issue](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails/issues/3)